# Cómo selecciono objetos que no aparecen en otra tabla en Django (Join)?

Tags: django, django-models

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Django, en mi base de datos tengo una serie de tablas: `Cliente`, `Coche`, `Alquiler` y `Registro`.

En alquiler tengo como `fk` el `dni` de cliente y la matricula de coche.

Bien, pues necesito sacar los coches que no aparecen en la tabla alquiler.

En SQL es un simple join, pero en Django empecé con ello hace una semana y por más que busco no sé por dónde tirar para hacer esto... He estado leyendo la documentación oficial, Django Girls, otros post en Stackoverflow, pero no me aclaro con esto.

Estos son mis modelos de `Alquiler` y `Coche`:

```
class Alquiler(models.Model):
    id_alq = models.SmallAutoField(db_column='ID_ALQ', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dni = models.ForeignKey('Cliente', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='DNI')  # Field name made lowercase.
    matricula = models.OneToOneField('Coche', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='MATRICULA')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fecha_alq = models.DateField(db_column='FECHA_ALQ')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fecha_dev = models.DateField(db_column='FECHA_DEV')  # Field name made lowercase.

class Coche(models.Model):
    matricula = models.CharField(db_column='MATRICULA', primary_key=True, max_length=7)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fecha_fab = models.IntegerField(db_column='FECHA_FAB')  # Field name made lowercase.
    marca = models.CharField(db_column='MARCA', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
    modelo = models.CharField(db_column='MODELO', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar exclude

```
alquiler = Alquiler.objects.filter(fecha_dev=date.today())
coche = Coche.objects.exclude(matricula__in = alquiler)
```

Comment: Hola edsantoshn, estoy intentando lo siguiente, pero me arroja todos los registros de coches: alquileres = Alquiler.objects.all() y después: disponibles = Coche.objects.exclude(matricula__in=alquileres), de esa forma, se supone que no me tendría que devolver los que aparecen en la tabla alquiler, no?

Comment: Si prueba de la siguiente forma: alquiler = Alquiler.objects.filter(fecha_dev=date.today()).values('matricula')
coche = Coche.objects.exclude(matricula__in = alquiler)

Si no le pasas la opcion de la fecha de retorno sea igual o menos a la fecha actual, te tomara todos los alquieres de los coches, esto te generara un error al momento de verificar que coches estan disponibles porque todos los coches estaran ocupados aunque se encuentren en el parking.